# How to express "evolved to eat X"?

Tags: translation, words

I'm having a hard time trying to find a way to express sentences like:

Humans **evolved to eat** smaller amounts of carbohydrates than we're used to eating today.

Penguins **evolved to eat** fish.

Could anyone suggest a close translation?

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would say 'Xを食べるよう進化した' ( X wo taberu you shinka shita ).